How to use tailwind css `theme` function with opacity modifiers
Is there anyway to use the theme() syntax for declaring a css variable with tailwind and using an opacity modifier after?
/*globals.css*/
@layer base {
  :root {
    /*these work fine*/

    --almost-black: 12 12 12;
    --body-color: var(--almost-black);
    --sub-text-color: 107 114 128;

    /*these break when used with opacity modifier syntax*/

    --background-color: theme("colors.gray.50");
    --color-primary: theme("colors.purple.600");
    --color-secondary: theme("colors.purple.300");
  }
}

// my tailwind config
const config: Config = {
 ...
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'body': 'rgb(var(--body-color))',
        'sub-text': 'rgb(var(--sub-text-color))',
        'background': 'rgb(var(--background-color))', // tried this just to sanity test but ofcourse it doesnt work because the output of `theme(colors)` is a hex value 
        'primary': 'var(--color-primary)',
        'secondary': 'var(--color-secondary)',
      }
    },
  },
};

Lets say I added this class to an element bg-body/50
Tailwind would know what I want and output some css like this
:is(.dark .dark\:bg-body\/50) {
    background-color: rgb(var(--body-color) / 0.5);
}

But if I wanted to use this, there does not seem to be a way. You'll notice that that page mentions opacity syntax, however it does not speak about using it with a variable, only a hard coded value.

You could consider using the CSS-native color-mix() function as part of the color values. This allows you to pass the <alpha-value> through without needing to "know" the color at runtime or the need to have them in the component RGB/HSL format:


tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'body': 'rgb(var(--body-color))',
        'sub-text': 'rgb(var(--sub-text-color))',
        'background': 'color-mix(in srgb, var(--background-color) calc(100% * <alpha-value>), transparent)',
        'primary': 'color-mix(in srgb, var(--color-primary) calc(100% * <alpha-value>), transparent)',
        'secondary': 'color-mix(in srgb, var(--color-secondary) calc(100% * <alpha-value>), transparent)',
      }
    },
  },
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.4"></script>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
@layer base {
  :root {
    /*these work fine*/

    --almost-black: 12 12 12;
    --body-color: var(--almost-black);
    --sub-text-color: 107 114 128;

    /*these break when used with opacity modifier syntax*/

    --background-color: theme("colors.gray.50"); 
    --color-primary: theme("colors.purple.600");
    --color-secondary: theme("colors.purple.300");
  }
}
</style>

<div class="bg-primary/75 w-10 h-10"></div>
<div class="bg-primary/50 w-10 h-10"></div>
<div class="bg-primary/25 w-10 h-10"></div>

<div class="bg-secondary/75 w-10 h-10"></div>
<div class="bg-secondary/50 w-10 h-10"></div>
<div class="bg-secondary/25 w-10 h-10"></div>




Stumbled across this today and discovered that using the rgb standard opacity will work here. I used this in a background image/overlay combination in my css file.
...
:root {
  --hero-awaiting: linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      theme(colors.maroon.dark/.3),
      theme(colors.maroon.dark/.3)
    ),
    url('../assets/hero-awaiting.jpg');
  }
...

